# GST/VAT tax. Why some countries return tax to tourists?

Tags: tax-law

Some countries return tax to tourists in airports.

I don't understand it. Why is it happening? What was the logic behind the decision? Why is it only related to purchase tax and not to income tax? Why is it so important to preserve original packaging?

It is obviously a sort of segregation and nationalism. Why did people vote for it?

I have heard that European countries are doing it along with Japan, Australia, and maybe some other countries are doing it as well...

Comment: This is a matter that people don't vote on. They vote for members of parliament, and the members of parliament enact various laws.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about political and social motivation, not the law or legal process.

Comment: @Nij While this question certainly has elements of "why such law?", it mostly boils around the lack of understanding how the laws governing that operate. What the law is that GST can be returned in airports? This is to be answered here, not on PoliticsSE.

Comment: That's not what the question asks, though. "Why do tourists get their tax back when residents don't?" can only be answered in the legal context by "That's what the law says to do". The question also clearly seeks the motivation of people: "What was the logic behind the decision?", "Why did people vote for it?" are both questions that have long been off-topic here. If you want to have a question that asks what the law is, ask it, but as of now, this one doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The law obliges businesses to charge  GST/VAT when the goods/services are delivered *within* the country. There is no such obligation on export, which means that foreigners can pay less.

Why? Because taxes of country X are generally supposed to be paid by tax residents of country X, not by everyone all over the world. Not imposing GST upon foreign shoppers makes the country more competitive and stimulates export which is good for the economy.

At airports the government returns GST because shops can't sell without GST to just anyone who promises to export the thing. If you export, you get GST back. If you don't, you don't.

Items need to be in original packaging because otherwise frequent travellers could exploit the scheme getting GST for their laptops every time they fly overseas.

Income tax and nationalism are not relevant here at all.

Answer (score 0):

### Because that’s the law

If you want to know why the law is that way, that’s a political question not a legal one. Post the question on the politics SE site.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Every law has it's vibe and vibe can be accepted as a valid argument in court in cases when the law is lacking some specifics.